# ot open output file first.exe: Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a C program in **VS code** but I keep getting this error:[image: as in this image]

I saved my file before running but it is still showing this error and I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: is first.exe still running?

Comment: Yes it is running but showing error

Comment: How can you `right a c program` and VSC **IS NOT** and IDE it is an editor

Comment: if your target .exe is still running, you won't be able to build and overwrite the running executable, and based on the error message I suspect that's what's happening. You need to quit/kill first.exe before you can build a new version. Not sure if VS code supports a debugging environment you should kill it from, but if nothing else you can X out the window or use Task Manager to kill it before trying to rebuild.

Comment: Yes I closed the window by X and again opened,saved again and ran but still getting error